# Natural boundary for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n!}}{n!}$

Tags: complex-analysis, absolute-convergence

In my complex variable course we are studying series convergence, using comparison test I determined that the series

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{n!}}{n!}
\end{equation}

has a convergence radius $R\leq 1$, so we know that at some point past the unitary disk is the first singularity, actually my professor told us that this series has a natural boundary, how could I prove it? he also asked for a single singularity in the boundary (as an example), any hint?

Comment: What is meant by a "natural boundary?" How are you defining singularity?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation#Natural_boundary

Comment: May help: [Fabry gap theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabry_gap_theorem), [Ostrowski–Hadamard gap theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski%E2%80%93Hadamard_gap_theorem). This is also relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90221/why-are-lacunary-series-so-badly-behaved

Comment: The power series has a limit when $z \rightarrow 1$, but its derivative hasn’t.

Comment: pick $e^{i\theta}$ any root of unity and show that $|f'(re^{i\theta})| \to \infty, r \to 1$ (this is very easy as for roots of unity $e^{in!\theta}=1$ for large enough $n$); as the roots of unity are dense in the unit circle, this shows that every point there is singular for $f'$, hence for $f$, so indeed the unit circle is natural boundary

Comment: $|z|=1$ converge.  $|z|\gt 1$ diverge.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your advises, but I don't understand why the if the derivative doesn't exist, it implies the function neither exists, is that true even when $|z|=1$ converges?

Comment: If $|z|=1$, the series is absolutely convergent, so you won't find a point on the unit circle where it doesn't converge. The point is: functions cannot be analytically continued around any point on the natural boundary.

Answer (score 1):

The series
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{n!}}{n!}$$
has a convergence radius $R=1$ and analytic in the unit disc $\mathbb{D}=\{|z|<1\}.$
We can show that the derivative $$f^\prime(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{n!-1}$$
has $\partial\mathbb{D}$ as a natural boundary directly (by showing the function tends to infinity on every radius whose argument is a rational multiple of $\pi$, see Conrad's comment) or by gap theorem.

Suppose that $f(z)$ has its analytic continuation on $\mathbb{D}\cup \{|z-z_0|<\delta\}$ with $z_0\in  \partial\mathbb{D}$. Then $f^\prime(z)$ should have its analytic continuation on $\mathbb{D}\cup \{|z-z_0|<\delta\}$. But it is impossible as stated above. So $f(z)$ has $\partial\mathbb{D}$ as a natural boundary.